# given a list of dates, how can i select the ones from the previous week?

Tags: python, datetime

i have a list conatining various dates

```
l = ['2021-07-13', '2021-07-14', '2021-07-15', '2021-07-16',
       '2021-07-17', '2021-07-18', '2021-07-19', '2021-07-20',
       '2021-07-21', '2021-07-22', '2021-07-23', '2021-07-24',
       '2021-07-25', '2021-07-26', '2021-07-27', '2021-08-02',
       '2021-08-03', '2021-08-04', '2021-08-05', '2021-08-06',
       '2021-08-07', '2021-08-08', '2021-09-02', '2021-07-28',
       '2021-08-27']
```

what i want to have is sort of a automated function that would return the ones from past week (in this case from `2021-08-02` to `2021-08-08`. Could this be done using `datetime` library?

right now the way i do it is just manually remove the ones that i don't need.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Share some code for people to help out in figuring out why it doesn't do what you want it to.

Comment: Take a date, add timedelta(days=1).. repeat..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using `datetime` and `pandas`

```
import datetime
from datetime import date
import pandas as pd

l = ['2021-07-13', '2021-07-14', '2021-07-15', '2021-07-16',
       '2021-07-17', '2021-07-18', '2021-07-19', '2021-07-20',
       '2021-07-21', '2021-07-22', '2021-07-23', '2021-07-24',
       '2021-07-25', '2021-07-26', '2021-07-27', '2021-08-02',
       '2021-08-03', '2021-08-04', '2021-08-05', '2021-08-06',
       '2021-08-07', '2021-08-08', '2021-09-02', '2021-07-28',
       '2021-08-27']

# calculate the week start date for the previous week
week_start = date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=date.today().weekday(), weeks=1)
# add seven days to the week start date to get the week end date
week_end = week_start + datetime.timedelta(days=7)
# use pandas to create a date range for the week
week = pd.date_range(week_start, week_end)
# convert your list to datetime
date_range = pd.to_datetime(l)
# filter to only keep the dates you want and convert back to strings
date_range[date_range.isin(week)].astype(str).tolist()

['2021-08-02',
 '2021-08-03',
 '2021-08-04',
 '2021-08-05',
 '2021-08-06',
 '2021-08-07',
 '2021-08-08']
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a two step process. First, we need the first and last day of last week. We can do this using `datetime.weekday` do get the current day of the week, and `timedelta` to subtract `weekday + 7` from today to get the first day of last week. We can then get the last day of last week by adding `timedelta(days=6)` to the first day.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date

today = datetime.today().date()
start = today - timedelta(days=today.weekday() + 7)
end = start + timedelta(days=6)
```

Now that we have the start and end dates, we can turn each date in the list into a `date` object and test whether it's between our two dates. We can roll this all up into a list comprehension to return a new list with only the dates we need:

```
last_week_dates = [d for d in l if start <= date.fromisoformat(d) <= end]
```

This creates a new list from `l` that only contains dates that are between the `start` and `end` dates, or in other words: all dates from last week. Putting it all together:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date

l = ['2021-07-13', '2021-07-14', '2021-07-15', '2021-07-16',
       '2021-07-17', '2021-07-18', '2021-07-19', '2021-07-20',
       '2021-07-21', '2021-07-22', '2021-07-23', '2021-07-24',
       '2021-07-25', '2021-07-26', '2021-07-27', '2021-08-02',
       '2021-08-03', '2021-08-04', '2021-08-05', '2021-08-06',
       '2021-08-07', '2021-08-08', '2021-09-02', '2021-07-28',
       '2021-08-27']

today = datetime.today().date()
start = today - timedelta(days=today.weekday() + 7)
end = start + timedelta(days=6)
last_week_dates = [d for d in l if start <= date.fromisoformat(d) <= end]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should first transform the string to a datetime object (strptime).
The second element of the tuble that is returned by the method isocalendar() gives you the week according to iso. This differs from US for example!
And then you only need to know the week you search for to filter.

```
    from datetime import datetime
    l = ['2021-07-13', '2021-07-14', '2021-07-15', '2021-07-16',
           '2021-07-17', '2021-07-18', '2021-07-19', '2021-07-20',
           '2021-07-21', '2021-07-22', '2021-07-23', '2021-07-24',
           '2021-07-25', '2021-07-26', '2021-07-27', '2021-08-02',
           '2021-08-03', '2021-08-04', '2021-08-05', '2021-08-06',
           '2021-08-07', '2021-08-08', '2021-09-02', '2021-07-28',
           '2021-08-27']
    week_we_search_for = 31
    for element in l:
        exDay = datetime.strptime(element, '%Y-%m-%d')
        week = exDay.isocalendar()[1]
        if week == week_we_search_for:
            print(exDay.year, exDay.month, exDay.day, week)
```